# Assigning timezone and converting

Tags: function, sqlite, datetime

I m trying to write an SQLite function and assign the timezone and then convert it.

I want to give function both the timezone I want to convert from and the timezone I want to convert in.

I m using replicate to integrate data from one database to another and the database server timezone can be different.

```
Datetime(now('EST'), PST)
```

Comment: SQLite does not support such functionality. Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am not able to access the link. I will try some other way.